# iCal recurrence rules, how do i specify all days in one month, forever?

Tags: icalendar, rfc2445

I was wondering how to do this, i thought that using

> FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=7;

meant every year in july, so that the event happpened every day of july each year, instead it means that the event happens only on the day specified by the event, so if the event starts on the 8th of november that recurrence rule means that it will happen of the 8th of July forever.

What's the correct way to specify each day in july?

Comment: This isn't related to php in any ways - even if you're generating the iCal with php.

Comment: @pozs yep sorry edited i was using a PHP library to parse this but it's not related

Answer (score 4, accepted):

alternatively:

```
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;BYMONTH=7
```

despite being conform to the standard (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#page-124), you should ensure that your most likely client supports this combination

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [rfc](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt) (around [Page 44]) i think if you didn't set a BY-rule, the suitable part from `DTSTART` will be used, so try to be more specific, like:

```
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=7;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA,SU
```

Comment: I don't know if it's my parser, but this is not correct, it returns no results, while the other answer return the correct results. I do not downvote because i don't know if it's wrong, just to let the other know :)